# How to execute many mysql queries with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop, split

Let's say I have a mysql table called "users", and that often I have to insert a record in another mysql table for each one of my user.

**For example:**

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query( $c,"SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE '$search'" );
while( $array = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
  // execute a query for each users
  mysqli_query( $c,"INSERT INTO example ( id, user_id, record1, record2, date ) VALUES ( NULL, '$array[user_id]', '$record1', '$record2', '$date' )" );
  $count++;
}
echo "$count rows added";
?>
```

If I have 1'000 or 10'000 users everything works great.

**But I was wondering, if I had 100,000 users (or even more) how should I do to avoid server errors / memory limit?**

There is a way to split my script?

Comment: Use something like `INSERT INTO example SELECT id FROM users` to reduce all this to a single query.... see [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html) for details

Comment: One query, insert into someTable Select some records from some other table, No need to bring anything into php in your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [INSERT ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) command.

```
<?php
    $result = mysqli_query( $c,"INSERT INTO example ( id, user_id, record1, record2, date ) SELECT NULL, user_id, '$record1', '$record2', '$date' FROM users WHERE '$search'" );
?>
```

Comment: thanks, do you know how to count the affected rows too with insert..select ?

Comment: I think usual [mysqli_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) should do the trick. Check it I don't have mysql on current machine to give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

Use mysql `INSERT .... SELECT`

```
mysqli_query($c,"INSERT INTO example (id, user_id, record1, record2, date)
SELECT NULL, user_id, '$record1', '$record2', '$date' FROM 
users WHERE '$search'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Never execute a query in a big loop, 1000 is already a very bad idea:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query( $c,"SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE '$search'" );
$insert = array();
while( $array = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
  // execute a query for each users
  $insert[] = "( NULL, '$array[user_id]', '$record1', '$record2', '$date' )";
}
mysqli_query( $c,"INSERT INTO example ( id, user_id, record1, record2, date ) VALUES " . implode(', ', $insert) );
echo count($insert) . " rows added";
?>
```

Comment: No need to do this either, it's massively inefficient.

Comment: No pulling the data from the database server to the web server so you can do something in php is inefficient. If you can do it all on the database server, you should. Not a php thing, if you did the same thing with a c# client program and sql server, it would be just as bad.